# Using EF5 to bind to Data Grid View issue

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm new to using EF and I'm currently using EF5 to attempt to bind data from a view to my data grid view in a WinForms App. I'm not sure how to do this properly, and I'm getting an error:

***Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().***

Here is my code:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
        {

            var qry = from col in context.vwSystemProperties
                      select new
                          {
                              SystemPropertyName = col.SystemPropertyName,
                              SystemPropertyEnumVal = col.SystemPropertyEnumVal,
                              SystemPropertyValue = col.SystemPropertyValue,
                              ApplicationScope = col.ApplicationScope,
                              CategoryScope = col.CategoryScope,
                              EntityScope = col.EntityScope,
                              VersionDate = col.VersionDate,
                              VersionUser = col.VersionUser
                          };


            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = qry;
            SystemPropertyDGV.DataSource = bs;

        }
```

I don't think I fully understand what the error is directing me to do.  I've done some brief searching but I don't think I've found what I need.  How is the DbSet supposed to be implemented and used to bind data to DGVs, or is there an easier way?

Can provide me with some insight on how to bind the qry object properly to the data grid view?  Right now I will just need to view the data, but going forward I would like to be able to access a row and update it based on ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `ToList()` method on the returned query.

Try to the following:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
{

    var qry = from col in context.vwSystemProperties
              select new
                  {
                      SystemPropertyName = col.SystemPropertyName,
                      SystemPropertyEnumVal = col.SystemPropertyEnumVal,
                      SystemPropertyValue = col.SystemPropertyValue,
                      ApplicationScope = col.ApplicationScope,
                      CategoryScope = col.CategoryScope,
                      EntityScope = col.EntityScope,
                      VersionDate = col.VersionDate,
                      VersionUser = col.VersionUser
                  };


    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = qry.ToList();
    SystemPropertyDGV.DataSource = bs;

}
```

Comment: I think you should explain how your answer differs from OP code :)

Comment: It worked...one of those ID10T errors on my part. Is there a best practices way of doing this that is different than what I'm attempting?  I see I can eliminate the BindingSource object and just do qry.ToList() on the DGV.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with Janus Grids, and adding ToList always solve the problem for me.